# Stylize text in WordPress Function

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello: I have added a function that creates a error message when a wrong password is entered for a password protected page. I am trying to change the color of the message to red, but with no luck. Here is the function:

```
function wpse_71284_custom_post_password_msg( $form )
{
// No cookie, the user has not sent anything until now.
if ( ! isset ( $_COOKIE[ 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH ] ) )
    return $form;


// Translate and escape.
$msg = esc_html__( 'Sorry but you have entered the incorrect password is wrong. Please try again.', 'your_text_domain' );

// We have a cookie, but it doesn’t match the password.
$msg = "<p class='custom-password-message'>$msg</p>";

return $msg . $form;
```

}

Trying to change color of text starting with "Sorry but..." I tried adding style but apparently syntax is incorrect. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does the generated html, and your css look like - thats where the problem will be

Comment: Your PHP function has nothing to do with the look of the message. You need to apply some `css` styling to it.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$msg = "<p class='custom-password-message'>$msg</p>";
```

into

```
$msg = "<p class='custom-password-message' style='color:red'>$msg</p>";
```

or better:

```
$msg = "<p class='custom-password-message error'>$msg</p>";
```

and then add to your style.css:

```
.error { color: red; }
```

Comment: Thank you. I think what I did wrong was added the a semicolon after red.